# Load excel macro to all of your workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, package

How can I take an Excel macro (VBA) and have it available in all of my excel workbooks?

Is there any way to distribute it as a package I can just load/install?

Can the same be done for a button that this macro is assigned to?

Thanks

Comment: Macros that I use across many workbooks I put in the Personal Workbook then they are available as needed.

Comment: If you want to distribute it as a package you can save your macros as an 'Add-In' and distribute that. They will then be available to all your users workbooks

Comment: Have a look this link : https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm Maybe this is what you want. If the macro is general I think it can be used to any kind of workbook where the sheets always different on each workbook. But if it's specific where (for example) your macro defined a variable to a sheet with name "tatata", but on the other workbook there is no sheet with name "tatata" then the macro will fail on this workbook. Etc.